# Struggling with Tic tac toe C++

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, input, while-loop

I'm relatively new to coding and have been tasked with creating a tic tac toe game in C++, I thought I had all the code done but there are various issues such as user input not being allowed, and only allowing to type one players name instead of two, any help/advice you could give me on how to make this work would be really appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int menumain;
int oneplayer = 'X';

char square1('1');
char square2('2');
char square3('3');
char square4('4');
char square5('5');
char square6('6');
char square7('7');
char square8('8');
char square9('9');

void toggleplayers() {
  if (oneplayer == 'X')
    oneplayer = 'O';
  else
    oneplayer = 'X';
}

char win()

{
  if (square1 == 'X' && square2 == 'X' && square3 == 'X') return 'X';
  if (square4 == 'X' && square5 == 'X' && square6 == 'X') return 'X';
  if (square7 == 'X' && square8 == 'X' && square9 == 'X') return 'X';
  if (square1 == 'X' && square5 == 'X' && square9 == 'X') return 'X';
  if (square3 == 'X' && square5 == 'X' && square7 == 'X') return 'X';
  if (square3 == 'X' && square6 == 'X' && square9 == 'X') return 'X';
  if (square1 == 'X' && square4 == 'X' && square7 == 'X') return 'X';
  if (square2 == 'X' && square5 == 'X' && square8 == 'X') return 'X';
  if (square1 == 'O' && square2 == 'O' && square3 == 'O') return 'O';
  if (square4 == 'O' && square5 == 'O' && square6 == 'O') return 'O';
  if (square7 == 'X' && square8 == 'X' && square9 == 'X') return 'X';
  if (square1 == 'O' && square5 == 'O' && square9 == 'O') return 'O';
  if (square3 == 'O' && square5 == 'O' && square7 == 'O') return 'O';
  if (square3 == 'O' && square6 == 'O' && square9 == 'O') return 'O';
  if (square1 == 'O' && square4 == 'O' && square7 == 'O') return 'O';
  if (square2 == 'O' && square5 == 'O' && square8 == 'O') return 'O';
  return '/';
}

int main() {
  int playerone, playertwo;
  system("cls");

  cout << "tic tac toe" << endl;
  cout << "-----------" << endl;
  cout << "Start game (1)" << endl;
  cout << "Quit game (2)" << endl;

  cout << "Press 1 or 2 to proceed." << endl;
  cin >> menumain;
  if (menumain == 2)

  {
    return 0;
  } else {
    cout << "Player One, please enter your name: " << endl;
    cin >> playerone;
    system("cls");

    cout << "Player Two, please enter your name: " << endl;
    cin >> playertwo;
    system("cls");

    int playermove;
    cout << "Choose a number between 1-9 to place!" << endl;
    cin >> playermove;

    if (playermove == 1)
      square1 = oneplayer;
    else if (playermove == 2)
      square2 = oneplayer;
    else if (playermove == 3)
      square3 = oneplayer;
    else if (playermove == 4)
      square4 = oneplayer;
    else if (playermove == 5)
      square5 = oneplayer;
    else if (playermove == 6)
      square6 = oneplayer;
    else if (playermove == 7)
      square7 = oneplayer;
    else if (playermove == 8)
      square8 = oneplayer;
    else if (playermove == 9)
      square9 = oneplayer;

    cout << "Tic tac toe!" << endl;

    cout << "------------" << endl;

    cout << " " << square1 << " | " << square2 << " | " << square3 << " "
         << endl;

    cout << " " << square4 << " | " << square5 << " | " << square6 << " "
         << endl;

    cout << " " << square7 << " | " << square8 << " | " << square9 << " "
         << endl;

    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << playerone << endl;
    cout << playertwo << endl;

    while (1) {
      if (win() == 'X') {
        cout << playerone << " wins!" << endl;
        break;
      }
      else if (win() == 'O') {
        cout << playertwo << " wins!" << endl;
        break;
      }
      toggleplayers();
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: **'user input not being allowed'**? It's upon you whether you allow it or not

Comment: You could simplify and shorten your code by using a 2 dimensional array for the board.

Comment: The way you've written your code, you're lucky that tic-tac-toe is only a 3 x 3 board.  What would your code look like if it were 10 x 10?  Identify the patterns in your code and see if there is a way to generalize -- the suggestion of the 2 dimensional matrix is just one step in shortening the code.

Comment: My advice is to use a *debugger* to help execute each statement separately.  Look at the values of variables as the execution continues.

Comment: Why are you assigning characters to integers.  I suggest you take a different course or throw the book in the trash.  The `char` type is for characters (letters).

Comment: Yes, toss your book in the trash.  If you are learning from an online tutorial, choose a different one.  Case in point, you prompt the player to enter their name and you read into an integer.  My understanding is names are `strings` of characters, not a number.  But, maybe your players have numbers as names.

Comment: Add in a loop for player's moves.  Presently your code is 1 pass.  You don't allow the player's to enter a 2nd move; there is no prompt.  You toggle the players, but don't get any input from them.

Comment: "the only winning move is not to play." -Joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a quick fix. copy, paste, compile and test. it will do the job in terms of a game. It works. It's tic tac toe. :D. Good luck with further adjustments.

These }; }; }; are just markers for myself since I edited this in a text editor and not an IDE. My suggestion, add a clause for a Draw. Because It will not do anything if there is no winner.

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  int menumain;
  int oneplayer = 'X';


  char square1('1');
  char square2('2');
  char square3('3');
  char square4('4');
  char square5('5');
  char square6('6');
  char square7('7');
  char square8('8');
  char square9('9');

  void toggleplayers()
  {
  if (oneplayer == 'X')
  oneplayer = 'O';
  else
  oneplayer = 'X';
  };

  char win()
  {
  if (square1 == 'X' && square2 == 'X' &&square3 == 'X')
  return 'X';
  if (square4 == 'X' && square5 == 'X' &&square6 == 'X')
  return 'X';

  if (square7 == 'X' && square8 == 'X' &&square9 == 'X')
  return 'X';

  if (square1 == 'X' && square5 == 'X' && square9 == 'X')
  return 'X';
  if (square3 == 'X' && square5 == 'X' &&square7 == 'X')
  return 'X';

  if (square3 == 'X' && square6 == 'X' &&square9 == 'X')
  return 'X';
  if (square1 == 'X' && square4 == 'X' &&square7 == 'X')
  return 'X';

  if (square2 == 'X' && square5 == 'X' &&square8 == 'X')
  return 'X';

  if (square1 == 'O' && square2 == 'O' &&square3 == 'O')
  return 'O';
  if (square4 == 'O' && square5 == 'O' &&square6 == 'O')
  return 'O';

  if (square7 == 'X' && square8 == 'X' &&square9 == 'X')
  return 'X';

  if (square1 == 'O' && square5 == 'O' && square9 == 'O')
  return 'O';
  if (square3 == 'O' && square5 == 'O' &&square7 == 'O')
  return 'O';

  if (square3 == 'O' && square6 == 'O' &&square9 == 'O')
  return 'O';
  if (square1 == 'O' && square4 == 'O' &&square7 == 'O')
  return 'O';

  if (square2 == 'O' && square5 == 'O' &&square8 == 'O')
  return 'O';

  return '/';
  };

  int main()
  {
  int playerone, playertwo;


  cout << "tic tac toe" << endl;
  cout << "-----------" << endl;
  cout << "Start game (1)" << endl;
  cout << "Quit game (2)" << endl;

  cout << "Press 1 or 2 to proceed." << endl;
  cin >> menumain;
  if (menumain == 2)

  {
  return 0;
  }
  else
  {

   cout << "Player One, please enter your name: " << endl;
    // cin >> playerone; create char array or string and ask for an input;


   cout << "Player Two, please enter your name: " << endl;
   // cin >> playertwo;  create char array or string and ask for an input;


   cout << "Tic tac toe!" << endl;

   cout << "------------" << endl;

   cout << " " << square1 << " | " << square2 << " | " << square3 << " " << endl;

   cout << " " << square4 << " | " << square5 << " | " << square6 << " " << endl;

   cout << " " << square7 << " | " << square8 << " | " << square9 << " " <<     endl;

   cout << " " << endl;
   cout << playerone << endl; //here replace playerone with char array variable or string;
   cout << playertwo << endl; //here replace playerone with char array variable or string;








    while(1)
    {


    int playermove;
    cout << "Choose a number between 1-9 to place!" << endl;
    cin >> playermove;

    if (playermove == 1)
    square1 = oneplayer;

    else if (playermove == 2)
    square2 = oneplayer;
    else if (playermove == 3)
    square3 = oneplayer;

    else if (playermove == 4)
    square4 = oneplayer;
    else if (playermove == 5)
    square5 = oneplayer;
    else if (playermove == 6)
    square6 = oneplayer;

    else if (playermove == 7)
    square7 = oneplayer;
    else if (playermove == 8)
    square8 = oneplayer;
    else if (playermove == 9)
    square9 = oneplayer;

    cout << "Tic tac toe!" << endl;

    cout << "------------" << endl;

    cout << " " << square1 << " | " << square2 << " | " << square3 << " " << endl;

    cout << " " << square4 << " | " << square5 << " | " << square6 << " " << endl;

    cout << " " << square7 << " | " << square8 << " | " << square9 << " " <<     endl;

    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << playerone << endl;
    cout << playertwo << endl;





    if (win() == 'X')
    {

     cout << playerone << " wins!" << endl;
        break;
    }

    else if (win() == 'O')
    {

     cout << playertwo << " wins!" << endl;
        break;

     };
    toggleplayers();
     };



     return 0;
     };


     };
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with your code.

> user input not being allowed

Actually you do get user input, *at the beginning* but not afterwards.

After *toggling* the player, you need to prompt the player for their move:

```
toggleplayers();
cout << "Player " << oneplayer << ", enter your move (1 - 9): ";
cout.flush();
cin >> playermove;
```